# Tkinter Buttons Disabled/Enabled on click

Tags: python, tkinter

For the code I am writing I am trying to set it up so that in a Tkinter UI, when you press a button, the button becomes disabled, and when you press a button while another button is disabled, the currently disabled button becomes enabled again.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def btnPressed(index):
    print("Button {0} disabled".format(index))
    for i in range(len(buttons)):
        print("Button {0}, State: {1}".format(index, buttons[index]['state']))
        if buttons[i]['state'] == 'disabled':
            buttons[i].configure(state = 'normal')
    buttons[index].configure(state = 'disabled')


root = tk.Tk()
buttons = []
btn1 = ttk.Button(root, text = "Button 1", command = lambda: btnPressed(0))
btn1.pack()
buttons.append(btn1)
btn2 = ttk.Button(root, text = "Button 2", command = lambda: btnPressed(1))
btn2.pack()
buttons.append(btn2)
btn3 = ttk.Button(root, text = "Button 3", command = lambda: btnPressed(2))
btn2.pack()
buttons.append(btn3)
root.mainloop()
```

Right now I can get it so that the buttons are disabling themselves, but then will not go back to their 'normal' state.  I tried doing some bug testing putting

`print("Button {0}, State: {1}".format(index, buttons[index]['state']))`

in the for loop so I could see every Buttons current state before it checked the if statement.

Every button, while on the UI is getting disabled, still had a state value of `'normal'`.  So obviously something is wrong, but I am not sure what that something is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the type of `buttons[index]['state']` you will see it is `<class '_tkinter.Tcl_Obj'>` not `string` which means your if statement always fails. You need to convert it to string to actually compare.

```
if str(buttons[i]['state']) == 'disabled':
```

By the way, you are using for loop already. Take advantage of it. You don't need `i` in that loop.

```
def btnPressed(index):
    for btn in buttons:
        if str(btn['state']) == 'disabled':
            btn.configure(state = 'normal')
    buttons[index].configure(state = 'disabled')
```

Comment: Beet me to it. I was just about to post my answer :P.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I can't figure out the IDLE debugger which is why I wasn't able to check the value type.

Answer (score 4):

You are using the `Button` class from ttk rather than tkinter. It's state attribute is an object, not a string.

To test if a ttk widget is in a specific state you can use the `instate` method. For example:

```
if buttons[i].instate(["disabled",]):
    ...
```

You could also use the `state` method, which returns the state. ttk states are more complex than tk states, so you get back a list. For example, `buttons[i].state()` will return `('disabled',)`

Also, are you aware that you can loop over the buttons without having to use an index? It will make your code much easier to read:

```
for button in buttons:
    if button['state'] == ...
```

Comment: For the `instate()` method, it's actually `button.instate([disabled])`.  You have to wrap the list in parenthesis since it's a function/method call.

Comment: @howdoicode: thanks for catching that! Nobody has noticed in over three years.